# What is the cost of creating an EOS account for users to at least be able to send tokens out and interact with dapps as of October 25, 2018?

Tags: accounts, account-creation

It's Oct 25, 2018. Recently the cost of creating an account was lowered. As a dapp developer, how much does it cost me to create a new account for a user to use my application? I know currently many new account creation services only preload your account with very small amounts of eos, which affects your ability to use the system by not being able to send things out or interact with dapps. What is the minimum eos needed to say make a few bets on betdice or play some game.